# Hamburger icon disappears after going to another page in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What I want to do is to maintain the hamburger icon across all pages of my mobile app. So i've done this in my navigation service

```
private static async Task NavigateAsync<T>(T page) where T : Page
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false);
            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(page, "Atras");

            await App.Navigator.PushAsync(page, true);
        }
```

When I navigate to another page, back button isn't showing neither hamburger button.
So, how can I do to keep hamburger icon showing in navigation bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using MasterDetail page to have a Hamburger Icon.

You will see the Hamburger icon as long as you are navigating between the detail pages.

But when you navigate away from the detail page via PushAsync or PushModalAsync you are in the Navigation of the detail page and you wont be able to see the Hamburger icon.

A work around possible is to deal the Navigation from detail page also as within the master-detail page or have all your pages be detail pages without any inner navigation.

Comment: I'm dealing with navigation inside detail of masterdetailpage like this: 
`<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Navigator">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainPage></pages:MainPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>`